# Estilizar la Toolbar android

Tags: android

Tengo un problema cuando pongo un estilo, si lo aplica al toolbar pero en la parte superior (color naranja mas oscuro donde esta el icono de la pila) ya no lo aplica.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi estilo

@color/colorPrimary
        @color/colorPrimaryDark
        @color/colorAccent

Le quite el Tema al manifest porque yo tengo un toolbar en mi archivo XML

Comment: eso depende de la versión de android en la que estas probando tu app, en las versiones previas a lollipop no es posible cambiar el colorPrimaryDark

Comment: Pues esque en otras actividades si se muestra pero a esas actividades no les quite en tema en el manifest

Comment: entonces muestra tu código

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeScot">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: ese es mi toolbar y adnetro tiene imagebutton y mi manifes de la actividad solamente le quite el NoActionBar

Comment: en tu pregunta hay una opcion de editar el contenido, podrias agregar le manifest, el archivo styles y el xml para poder saber de donde surje el problema. Revisa esta liga http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Answer (score 0):

Aquí el color que aplica en el "Status bar" es `colorPrimaryDark`, definelo con el color que deseas ahí, dentro de colors.xml:

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Comment: ya lo tenia pero no queda

Comment: <style name="ThemeScot" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF9800</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#F57C00</item>
    </style>